# esxi ssh connection get cpu usage

Tags: shell, vmware, esxi

as title described, I have a ssh connection between my laptop and esxi host, I want to be able to get cpu usage using this shell. I tried to use top, but there isn't a top command. is there any way to do it? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, try the the [esxtop](https://www.vmware.com/pdf/esx2_using_esxtop.pdf) command.